# WSO2 AM 1.8 integration with WSO2 BAM 2.5

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-bam

I am trying to integrate **WSO2 BAM 2.5** with **WSO2 AM 1.8** by referring this document. .https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM150/Monitoring+Using+WSO2+BAM. But i am getting error in BAM console .I configured it in windows 7.Any help to fix if,Thanks in advance

**Error**

> [2015-01-13 14:34:03,045]  WARN
>   {org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping} -  got
>   exception trying to get groups for user Jamshi
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: id: Jamshi: no such
>   user
>
> ```
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:255)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:182)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:375)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:461)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:444)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getUnixGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:68)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:45)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getGroups(Groups.java:79)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getGroupNames(UserGroupInformation.java:1030)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.HadoopDefaultAuthenticator.setConf(HadoopDefaultAuthenticator.java:62)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getAuthenticator(HiveUtils.java:222)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:270)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.service.HiveServer$HiveServerHandler.<init>(HiveServer.java:136)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:63)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
>     at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.getConnection(HiveExecutorServiceI
> ```
>
> mpl.java:577)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:
>   224)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl$ScriptCallable.call(HiveExecutorServiceImpl.java:
>   192)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing BAM on Windows please make sure to follow the corresponding Windows-specific doc: https://docs.wso2.com/display/BAM241/Installing+on+Windows

According to the doc, try to install Cywin into C drive and make sure no space in file path and add "C:\cygwin64\bin" to the windows PATH, also make sure BAM running user has rights to run cygwin commands ( in default nothing to do in windows, unless you may set some special permission ).

Please note that we are not recommending to run BAM in windows in production environment due to compatibility of Cassandra , Hadoop.

If installing cygwin64 doesn't resolve the issue, please attach the conf files in both BAM and APIM (/repository/conf).

Also, the integration instructions that you are following are for API Manager 1.5.0 (see AM150 in the path). This is the 1.8.0 version: https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM180/Publishing+API+Runtime+Statistics

Alternatively, you can use [WSO2 API Cloud](http://wso2.com/cloud/api-cloud) (SaaS version of API Manager) in which everything is preconfigured and works out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

In this case the problems is in the max Windows path length.
When BAM is trying to run am_stats_script to make statistics, it has to copy to tmp folder some library. To do that it has to create many nasted folders. And in one moment there occurs the problem with path length. 
I found it when I was analyzing log output and found "No such file" exception.

The simple solution is to move to Linux platform (as Jamsheer did). On Linux there isn`t such problem.